# Remove extra </div> tags from in front of </body> tag? (Google dynamic remarketing api)

Tags: magento, dynamic, analytics

I'm trying to enable dynamic remarketing tags, Fooman dynamic remarketing is installed. Google's Tag assistant reports that the script should be immediately before the  closing tag, the Google api seems to add  twice after  
The data is all good, it's simply not working because of these extra s from what I can see. How can I locate and remove these? I've done some investigation in the relevant files but can't find anything likely to cause the problem.

The issue may be part of the Google api, if I disable this then the additional  tags disappear.

My other option is to manually add the remarketing snippet, I've tried this through Design -> Footer -> Miscellaneous html, whilst this is correctly placed before the  and has no extra  tags the dynamic data fields are not populated. Am I missing something? Is it being treated as flat html rather than dynamic?

Magento 1.9.0

Hoping someone can help.
Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 0):

Want to try this one? Also regarding script should be immediately before the closing tag, this is not a big issue. http://ecommppc.com/2014/09/05/setting-up-dynamic-remarketing-on-your-magento-webstore-using-google-tag-manager/

Comment: Thanks, wish I'd seen this sooner, nice walkthrough. I'm the meantime I ended up editing the main page template ../page/2columns-right.phtml and repositioning some of the content. This put the Google script immediately before </body> and tag manager was happy. Ads were not being shown whilst there was anything between </noscript> and </body> Cheers, Rob..